# Query returns two lines

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, case

I have a table that has a column called `type` which has either a value of invoiced or order and then another column holding the value along with a column holding the customer number etc.

I have written a script :-

```
select 
    customer, 
    (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'INVOICED' THEN SUM(INVTOTAL) else 0 END) AS INVTOTAL, 
    (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'ORDERS' THEN SUM(INVTOTAL) else 0 END) AS ORDERTOTAL
from 
    salestable
```

Why does it return the following?

```
customer      INVTOTAL   ORDERTOTAL
Joe Bloggs   1000            0
Joe Bloggs     0          1300
```

instead of

```
customer      INVTOTAL   ORDERTOTAL
Joe Bloggs   1000            1300
```

Sorry to ask such a novice question but I am new to SQL and learning it...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Clearly that is two rows in salestable

Answer (score 2):

Your query was missing a `group by`. Also use `sum` around `case` to avoid multiple rows.

```
select customer, 
       sum(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'INVOICED' THEN INVTOTAL else 0 END) AS INVTOTAL, 
       sum(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'ORDERS'   THEN INVTOTAL else 0 END) AS ORDERTOTAL
from salestable
group by customer
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a group by with the customer that will avoid the multiple rows.check the fiddle below.

```
create table tb1
(customer varchar(25),
 type varchar(25),
 invoice numeric(18,2)
 );

 insert into tb1(customer,type,invoice) values('Joe Bloggs','INVOICED',1000);
 insert into tb1(customer,type,invoice) values('Joe Bloggs','ORDERS',1000);

select customer, 
sum(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'INVOICED' THEN  sum(invoice) else 0 END) AS INVTOTAL, 
sum(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'ORDERS'   THEN  sum(invoice) else 0 END) AS ORDERTOTAL
from tb1
group by customer
```

[fiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45db7/3)

You need to put the entire case statment inside sum() 
inorder to avoid grouping by `type` also else you will get this below error

```
    Column 'tb1.type' is invalid in the select list because it is 
not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because select returns a row for each row in the table matching the where filters.  If no filters, then a result row for every row in table.  If you want to "join" the rows, you could try grouping by the customer, like:

```
SELECT customer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'INVOICED' THEN INVTOTAL ELSE 0 END) as INVTOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'ORDERS'   THEN INVTOTAL ELSE 0 END) as ORDERTOTAL
FROM salestable
GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: there is no ordertotal

Comment: oops, right.  was just looking at final result table